# Should I remove wildcard domain class imports in my gsp's

Tags: grails

I'm looking at at existing appliucation that use's grails 2.1.0.

I noticed the following in the main layout view (All other views use this layout).

```
<%@ page import="com.mysite.domains.*" %>
```

Some of the domain classes under this folder are directly used in the views thoughout the application. But they are all most certainly not used or needed in the views. For example **Category**:

```
<g:select name='category' value="${beanInstance?.category?.categoryKey}"
              from='${Category.findAllByActive(true)}' optionValue="name"
              optionKey="categoryKey"></g:select>
```

Is Grails smart enough that it only imports them if it knows they are used in the currernt view?

Or should I remove this wildcard import and indivudually specify each required class?

Thanks

Comment: Please don't do this, but use Taglib for that :) You should not access DB from view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GSPs are eventually compiled into class which extends org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage.
The page import directive are translated to regular package members import instructions. Import only tells the compiler where to look for symbols so importing all classes in a package does not have a special overhead.